# What do comparison operators do on dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I came across this:

```
>>> d1 = {"john":40, "peter":45}
>>> d2 = {"john":466, "peter":45}
>>> d1 > d2
False
```

What does the comparison operator do while comparing two dicts and how does it output `False`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since these dicts have equal length, we find the smallest key for which the corresponding values are unequal, i.e. `'john'`.  Then the dicts are compared on the value of that key.

Demo:

```
>>> d1 = {"john":40, "peter":45}
>>> d2 = {"john":466, "peter":45}
>>> d1 < d2
True
>>> d2['john'] = 39
>>> d1 < d2
False
```

This basic idea is essentially unchanged since [Guido's commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/a0a69b8b429f3d4c91f1c432247cfda017505976) from over 20 years ago:

```
$ git show a0a69b8
commit a0a69b8b429f3d4c91f1c432247cfda017505976
Author: Guido van Rossum <guido@python.org>
Date:   Thu Dec 5 21:55:55 1996 +0000

    Experimental new implementation of dictionary comparison.  This
    defines that a shorter dictionary is always smaller than a longer one.
    For dictionaries of the same size, the smallest differing element
    determines the outcome (which yields the same results as before,
    without explicit sorting).
```

It is not documented, and the dict comparison code is removed in Python 3, so I wouldn't rely on that for anything important.  The relevant CPython source is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2097b9e0ef32ab7a0d745edc0f707c615780c006/Objects/dictobject.c#L1875).

*Fun fact:* Apparently, in older versions of Python, some dict comparisons could crash the runtime and could even [cause Windows 98 to reboot](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/95bf9390a488004f66db1eccaa049203ef8ab5b3).  Heh.

Answer (score 2):

> Dictionaries, like sets, do not maintain a well-defined order on their elements.
>   Furthermore, the concept of a subset is not typically meaningful for dictionaries, so
>   the
>   dict
>   class does not support operators such as
>   `<`
>   . Dictionaries support the notion
>   of equivalence, with
>   d1 == d2
>   if the two dictionaries contain the same set of key-
>   value pairs.

So what you can do is,

```
d1 == d2  #d1 is equivalent to d2
d1 != d2  #d1 is not equivalent to d2
```

However you cannot do `> < >= <=`

This is in python 3.

```
>>> a
{1: '1', 2: '2'}
>>> b
{1: '1', 2: '2'}
>>> a==b
True
>>> a<b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#31>", line 1, in <module>
    a<b
TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < dict()
>>> a>b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    a>b
TypeError: unorderable types: dict() > dict()
>>>
```

However in python 2 take a look at this,

```
>>> a = {2:2}
>>> b = {2:2}
>>> a==b
True
>>> a<b
False
>>> a>b
False
```

But when the `key` is same and `value` is different

```
>>> a={3:1}
>>> b={3:2}
>>> a<b
True
>>> a>b
False
```

Again if `value` is same,

```
>>> a={3:0}
>>> b={3:0}
>>> a==b
True
>>> a<b
False
>>> a>b
False
```

But notice this when value in first `dict` is greater

```
>>> a={3:200}
>>> b={3:10}
>>> a<b
False
>>> a>b
True
```

Till now we had same `key` different `values` now let's change that,

Now **Same value different key**

```
>>> a={2:10}
>>> b={3:10}
>>> a<b
True
>>> a>b
False
>>> 
>>> a={10:10}
>>> b={1:10}
>>> a<b
False
>>> a>b
True
```

What can you get from this, Python 2 either key is checked and if it's same, **only then** ,value is checked. Now let's have different key , different values,

```
>>> a={10:10}
>>> b={1:100}
>>> a<b
False
>>> a>b
True
```

Aha! In this case you can infer that `key` is the first thing that will be checked and if they are the same only then value will be checked. Now let's say we have more than one `key:value` pair in our dictionary?

```
>>> a={10:10,1:10}
>>> b={10:10,2:10}
>>> a<b
True
>>> a>b
False
>>> a={10:10,200:10}
>>> b={10:10,1:10}
>>> a<b
False
>>> a>b
True
```

So it means. Every `key` is checked and then if `key` is same value will be checked. Ah but how does key checking work ? For that take a look at [dict_compare source code](http://%20svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/dictobject.c)

**NOTE:** The method cmp() returns the sign of the difference of two numbers : -1 if x < y, 0 if x == y, or 1 if x > y

So basically What happens is that to compare dicts A and B, lengths are compared first (equal no problem). If they are unequal, then return cmp(len(A), len(B)).

Next, find the key `akey` in A that is the smallest key for which

`akey not in B or 
A[akey] != B[akey]` -->(This happens only when akey is present in B).

(If there is no such key, the dicts are equal.)

**Also** (must) find the smallest key bkey in B for which

`bkey not in A`
 or `A[bkey] != B[bkey]` -->(This happens only when bkey is present in B).

If akey != bkey, then return cmp(akey, bkey). Else return cmp(A[akey], B[bkey])

```
>>> a={10:10,200:10}
>>> b={10:10,1:10}
>>> a<b
False
>>> a>b
True
>>> cmp(200,1)
1
>>> cmp(1,200)
-1
```

So the smallest key in `A` not in `B` is `200` similarly `1` in  `A`.

Now internaly python compares them according to the given above algorithm so `cmp(200,1)` would be calculated when `a>b` is done. Else `cmp(1,200)` if `a<b` is done.

But this was removed completely from python 3. This doesn't work in python 3.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> d2>d1
True
>>> d3 = {"john":40, "peter":45}
>>> d1>=d3
True
```

As you can see above, comparison on dictionaries done by key. These are equals;

```
>>> res = []
>>> for key1,val1 in d1.iteritems():
...     res.append(val1 >d2[key1] )
>>> res
[False, False]
>>> all(res)
False
>>> d1 > d2
False
```