# Why do dict1.items() <= dict2.items() and dict1.viewitems() <= dict2.viewitems() return different results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I am confused as to why .items() returns a different result than .viewitems() when comparing two dictionaries as a list.

```py
# python 2.7
d1 = {'1': '10', '2': '20'}  # two key-value pairs
d2 = {'3': '30', '4': '40', '5': '50'}  # three key-value pairs
print d1 <= d2  # True
print d1.items() <= d2.items()  # True
print d1.viewitems() <= d2.viewitems()  # False
print d1.items()  # [('1', '10'), ('2', '20')]
print d1.viewitems()  # dict_items([('1', '10'), ('2', '20')])
```

Seems like the main difference between .items() and .viewitems() is
that .items() returns a list and viewitems() returns a dict_items thingy.

Is it recommended to just use d1 <= d2 rather than viewitems or items when comparing the size between dictionaries?

Also, how to make this compatible with Python 3?

Comment: If you want to compare *sizes* of dictionaries, do so explicitly: `len(d1) < len(d2)`.

Comment: boo, python 2.x!

Comment: Python 2.7 did not define what, exactly, `d1 <= d2` would mean. From https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#comparisons:  "Mappings (instances of dict) compare equal if and only if they have equal (key, value) pairs. Equality comparison of the keys and values enforces reflexivity.

Outcomes other than equality are resolved consistently, but are not otherwise defined."

Comment: Unless you are maintaining legacy Python 2 code, you shouldn't be worried about the semantics; `d1 <= d2` is a type error in Python 3, forcing you to use `len(d1) <= len(d2)`.

Comment: @chepner yes, looking for python 3 compatibility

Comment: *Also, how to make this compatible with Python 3?* - make which part specifically?  You demonstrated multiple things here.

Comment: What do you want the rule to be, that decides whether one dict's contents are "less than" the others?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inconsistent behaviour between dict.values() and dict.keys() equality in Python 3.x and Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55026840/inconsistent-behaviour-between-dict-values-and-dict-keys-equality-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
d1 <= d2  # True
```

It's complicated.  And it's implementation detail. See [What do comparison operators do on dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44772257/674039) TL;DR: a shorter dictionary is always smaller than a longer one in Python 2.x, but dicts are not orderable at all in Python 3.x.

```
d1.items() <= d2.items()  # True
```

This is a [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) comparison of lists. That `True` result is reliable, since *every* key in `d1` is less than *any* key of `d2`. To make this code cross-compatible, you would have to convert to list explicitly.

```
d1.viewitems() <= d2.viewitems()  # False
```

This is a subset-like check. That `False` result is reliable, because `d1` is not a "subdict" of `d2`. To make this code cross-compatible, use `six.viewitems` or similar.

> Is it recommended to just use d1 <= d2 rather than viewitems or items when comparing the size between dictionaries?

Neither, use `len(d1) <= len(d2)` to compare the size between dictionaries.

Comment: Wait, so both the True and False results are reliable?  We are migrating from python 2 to 3, and a linter replaced viewitems() with items() and then caused a unit test to fail.  If .items() and .viewitems() do something different than simply comparing sizes of dictionaries, then what should I do?

Comment: It depends, do you need cross-compatible code or just Python 3 compatible code?  Did the unit test fail on Py 2 or Py 3?

Comment: Cross compatible code.  Unit test failed on python 2, but the logic was kinda vague whether they are comparing keys, subset, or length of the dictionaries.

Comment: Your linter did the right thing (replacing viewitems with items) to convert py2 -> py3 code.  But this is not a cross-compat code.  For that you'll need to use `six.viewitems` or similar, as the answer mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I've answered a similar question here: [Inconsistent behaviour between dict.values() and dict.keys() equality in Python 3.x and Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55026840/inconsistent-behaviour-between-dict-values-and-dict-keys-equality-in-python/55027650#55027650)

The key thing to note is that `dict.viewitems()` is a `Set-like` object.  Which means that when you do `d1.viewitems() <= d2.viewitems()` you are comparing checking if `d1.viewitems()` is a *subset* of `d2.viewitems()`, not the length comparison you expected.  See the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sets.html#set-objects

> ```
> Operation         Equivalent  Result
> s.issubset(t)     s <= t      test whether every element in s is in t
> s.issuperset(t)   s >= t      test whether every element in t is in s
> ```

**Note:** because `dict.viewitem()` is a `collections.Set` object, it doesn't have `.issubset` or `.issuperset` methods like `set` does.

Observe the following:

```
>>> d1 = {'a': 0}
>>> d2 = {'a': 1}
>>> d3 = {'a': 0, 'b': 1}
>>> d1.viewitems() <= d3.viewitems()
True     # because [('a', 0)] is a subset of [('a', 0), ('b', 1)]
>>> d2.viewitems() <= d3.viewitems()
False    # because [('a', 1)] is not a subset of [('a', 0), ('b', 1)]
```

To answer your question though - as others have mentioned, to compare size, use `len(d1) <= len(d2)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your stated purpose is to compare dictionary sizes ... which you haven't done at all.  You need to use `len` for that.

What you *did* do is comparing items of two very different types.  `items` returns a list of tuples, which are easily compared by the well-known algorithms: check elements in the given order for relative value.  Tuple comparison is familiar to most of us.

However, a `dict_view` is a dynamic view object, *not* a simple list of values.  You're comparing a more complex object, not merely running down an obvious list of values.  The ordering and comparison definition are not readily visible to us mere mortals.

Comment: The ordering and comparison definition is visible; the definition of the dict view objects specify that they implement the `collections.abc.Set` ABC, and while the ABC itself doesn't actually say what `__le__`/`<=` should do, any reasonable implementer would follow the rules `set` follows, namely, returning `True` if the the left hand side is a subset of, or equal to, the right hand side.